# How to pause while loop until a button is pressed

Tags: java, android

How do I pause a while loop until a button is pressed?

I want to have a while loop which restarts everytime a button is pressed. Is this possible?

Comment: put the while loop in a function that is called everytime the button is pressed. is that answers the question or am I missing something?

Comment: You could achieve the "pausing" by `sleep`ing the current thread.

Comment: how would I set the sleep until the button is pressed, not a time?

Comment: You don't. Android, like nearly all modern GUI environments, works on an event-driven model. Please adjust your implementation to take this into account.

Answer (score 6):

### Answer 1

You could have a button that will exit the loop when it is pressed, and then call the method immediately after it exits.

```
public void process(){
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
        // do stuff
        if (buttonPress) done = true;  // ends loop
        else buttonPress = false;  // insures buttonPress is false, not needed
    }
}
```

### Answer 2

You could also just sleep the thread for a certain amount of time, then it will automatically continue when the thread "wakes up".

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
boolean isRunning = true;
        public void run() {
             while(isRunning){
                 // do stuff
                 if(buttonPress) Thread.sleep(4000); // or however long you want
             }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

### Answer 3

Have a loop within the loop

```
while(listening) {
    while(!buttonPress) {
    }
    buttonPress=false;
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

`(System.in.available() == 0){
//Do whatever you want
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
while (button.isPressed()) {
    break;
} 
while (!button.isPressed()) {
    // do your things...
}
```